# How to group categorical column followed by numerical column, and based on this group to bin the numerical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset, in which the column "Type" is basically shapes, and corresponding to that, the column "Volume" consists of volume to that shape

Now I need to do the following task:

1. Group-by shape
2. And for each shape, group-by volume
3. And for each shape and volume, define a range and form bins

Input:

```
 Type             Volume

 Cylinder          100
 Square            300
 Cylinder          200
 Oval              100
 Square            320
 Cylinder          150
 Oval              600
 Round             1000
 Square            900
 Round             1500
```

Output:

```
 Type              Volume       Bin

 Cylinder          100            1
 Cylinder          150            1
 Cylinder          200            2
 Oval              100            1
 Oval              600            3
 Round             1000           1
 Round             1500           2
 Square            300            1
 Square            320            1
 Square            900            3
```

The bin would be as below:

1.Cylinder -> Bin1(100-200), Bin2(201-300) ....

2.Oval -> Bin1(100-200), ..... Bin3(500-600)....
....

Code:

```
  grouped=df_dim.groupby('Type', as_index=False)
  def test(group):
     return group.reset_index()
  def group_vol(group):
     groupedVol = 
         group.groupby(pd.cut(group["Target_BrimVol"],
         np.arange(0,5000,200)),as_index=False)

     return groupedVol.apply(test)

  gr = grouped.apply(group_vol)
  print(gr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the code below.

```python
testdf = df.groupby('Type',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(pd.cut(x["Vol"],np.arange(x["Volume"].min(),x["Volume"].max(),200)),as_index=False).apply(test))
```

What is happening here is, the first `groupby` basically groups the Dataframe into "Type" category and then you want to group it based on the ranges. For this you can group it again using the lambda function using `pd.cut` function to make small cuts of interval based on your range. In this case I am just taking the max and min value and cutting it in intervals of 200. After this , if you want to merge the outputs back together forming a Dataframe again, using one more apply to merge them back. 
like this,

```python
def test(group):
   #Write your function here. Whatever you want to perform.
   return group.merge(group)
```

And I am using `as_index=False` to reset the index here so that the dataframe is rearranged as per the new index.

Hope this helps.

Edit:- 
For bins, you do not have to worry because each `groupby` creates a new index, which you can use for your purpose. As in,

```python
Index1  Index2  Type  Volume
0 0 Cylinder  100
0 0 Cylinder  140
0 1 Cylinder  250
1 0 Oval  154
1 4 Oval 999
2 1 Circle  328
```